# What is error: "NSInvalidArgumentException reason: Application tried to present modal view controller on itself

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I try to run the app it crashes me 
This is the message I get:

```
2014-07-25 14:40:28.116 X[13023:60b] (null)
2014-07-25 14:40:29.113 X[13023:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <GKHostedAuthenticateViewController: 0x10d625f90>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001028a1495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001024e399e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   UIKit                               0x0000000101190cdc -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4100
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102896f1c __invoking___ + 140
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102896dc4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000101181abc -[_UIDelayedPresentationContext finishDelayedPresentation:] + 201
    6   GameCenterUI                        0x000000010c97f330 __41-[GKRemoteViewController setupRemoteView]_block_invoke + 37
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102896f1c __invoking___ + 140
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102896dc4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010340a851 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010341d72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010340d3fc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 354
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001028ff289 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010284c854 __CFRunLoopRun + 1764
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010284bd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103efdf04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000101090e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    17  X                              0x00000001000064c3 main + 115
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010366e5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What could be the problem? 
Until now it worked well suddenly it happened 
Thank you to all helpers

update:
@Sviatoslav Yakymiv
found this i think

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;


GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
{
    // ios 5.x and below
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         [self checkLocalPlayer];
     }];
}
else
{
    // ios 6.0 and above
    [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && viewcontroller)
        {
            [viewcontroller presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [self checkLocalPlayer];
        }
    })];
}
```

}

What I can change it without a crash?
thanks

Comment: change ur [viewcontroller presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil] to [self presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: error:
no visible interface for declares the selector presentviewcontroller:animated:completion:'

Comment: can u post your full code.we want know what are the things u did?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are attempting to present controller from itself.
Probably your code contains something like following:

```
[self presentViewController:self completion:nil];
```

Now after I saw your code I can provide working code:

Replace

```
[viewcontroller presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: `[presentingViewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];`
now its good thanks

Answer (score 10):

Same error for me when I accidentally called

```
presentViewController:
```

***twice***.

Answer (score 2):

You have not created your xib properly. Check all your connections and delegates. Your last changes to xib have introduced some problems. This exception throws when your xib / storyboard are not proper.